# Java API to make a phone call

Tags: java, phone-call

Is there any Java API to make a phone call to a mobile(provided that service provider support will be arranged to make that call)?

```
myProgram(A) --> Java API to make a call like Skype(B) --> PSTN/Mobile network support(c)
```

Module A will be my Java code and it'll call the B's API which will in turn transfer the call to my service provider.

I'm looking for an API at level B. Also, I'm not using Android. I want to run this code on my server.

I tried and landed upto skype.
For using Skype, Skype should be installed on the machine(which I don't want).

Is there any other solution to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Did you already take a look on [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/)? There is a [Java API](http://asterisk-java.org/).

Comment: Asterisk under GNU GPL and Asterisk-Java under Apache License, thus both free.

Comment: Doesn't Asterisk need to be configured for my service provider?

Comment: But I think it's Linux only

Answer (score 3):

There is [Java Telephone API (JTAPI)](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/jtapi.html). You can take a look at that. It have different implementations, like [xtapi](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xtapi/), [gjtapi](http://gjtapi.sourceforge.net/). I have worked with xtapi.

It allows you to make/receive a call.

Comment: Can you add some code here? Also, how you configured your PSTN/Mobile network provider for this?

Comment: from where i download the javax.telephony jar