# How can we implement calling functionality using Java?

Tags: java

Is there any way to implement calling functionality from java application either by using telephone or using mobile or any other device ?

Comment: what?  Could you be clearer?

Comment: He want to initiate a call via Java. Like calling your friend on your phone.

Comment: @newboyhun yes you are right.

Comment: I don't see why people are downvoting this question.

Comment: There is a question on SO , but doesn't have any accepted answer, take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696202/java-api-to-make-a-phone-call

Comment: This is not a programming language question. Making phone calls requires hardware connected to a telephone service provider. Once you have that, a call can be made using essentially any language

Answer (score 0):

If you want to initiate your call from a JavaSE  application then the VoIP is your  way, you have to use an IPBX  like Asterisk, and configure an axternal gateway to the gsm network. And the java app have to communicate with th IPBX .

Comment: Can you provide any example?

Comment: Take a look here http://www.asterisk-java.org/development/

Comment: try [this](http://wiki.e1550.mobi/doku.php?id=installation) if you want to use your own sim card when calling